# google place api photo references

Tags: php, google-api

I am using Google Api for getting photos from location .
i got the call and it working correctly.
but i have a problem.can be change google photo reference. because 
i want to save image reference according to place id.
in future google photo reference will be change or not.

```
  "places": [
{
  "place_id": "ChIJheBKaKGuEmsRKk48IGMVojU",
  "name": "Thai Spice House",
  "lon": 151.228688,
  "lat": -33.82916,
  "address": "271 Military Road, Cremorne NSW 2090, Australia",
  "images": [
    "CnRoAAAAbMcJPxxWzU1pj_zSHqMtLlLBe2o6_pmd2ZHhJdxBO3UG4Q1BYxr4x834Bp5UmDrZhmSxVzeXb-nqHIYqLWcTdjQFFnuvp_DgK7c59wEvnu_AkH3KLNpqm4BtFw5wTWeZOgmwNnTEEoevb5-AxfsipxIQ9TnIAApazfKw1KuO7ZtEMhoUWs9FAN78M3O26af9StPMx3fej5E"
  ]
```

this image reference can be change in future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every value except `place_id` can potentially change at anytime.